# LED and motor connected in parallel

Tags: led, dc-motor

[image] [image]

i built a vibrobot pictured above. 
i now want to connect a led to the working system.
sadly when i connect the led in parallel, it will not work.

power source is a CR2032 3V coin cell. motor is small pager dc motor.
im trying to keep number of components at a minimum

Comment: What doesn't work the LED or the whole system?   First off I don't see a current limiting resistor in series with your LED.  Do you have one of those?

Comment: i don't use a limiting resistor as they are not absolutely necessary trying to keep it simple. i connected a resistor just to check but it doesn't change the situation. what is not working is the LED will not light up when the motor is connected if i disconnect the motor LED will work ok.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? It's clearly asked and has a clear diagram.

Comment: I'm thinking that with the DC motor in parallel with the LED that all your current is flowing through the very low resistance of the motor.   So you're not getting enough current flowing through the LED for it to turn on.   Just a guess.  Did you take any voltage or current measurements?  You could try adding some resistance between the motor and the battery just as an experiment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be driving a red LED from a 3V coin cell.  Red LED voltage drop is typically on the order of 1.8V.  You're overloading the LED by doing it this way, and it is likely sinking the current that should be going to your motor.  Minimally, you need a resistor in series with the LED to limit its current.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Ryan said about the LED being overdriven and the battery voltage thereby collapsing, consider the load of the led on the small battery.  A CR2032 coin cell will struggle just to run the motor.  Another 10 or 20 mA for the LED, even when driven correctly, is a significant additional load on the already overtaxed battery.

Do you really need this thing to light up?  If so, get a efficient LED and run it as the lowest possible current to get the minimum necessary brightness.

Comment: "run it as the lowest possible current". Maybe you should tell him about a series resistor for the LED. The Fritzing diagram in the question doesn't have one.

Comment: @steven: I did by reference to Ryan's post, but I'll make it explicit here too: You need a resistor in series with the LED to keep the current to acceptable and predictable limits. Higher resistor means less current, which means less light, but also means less strain on the battery.